# Dojo toolkit, Binding & partial view (using contentpane)

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, binding, dojo

I've got problem with ContentPane & Binding.
I've got two solution with different structure.

My first solution file system :

```
 - Home.html
 - MyModule.html  
 - MyView.html
```

*Home.html* contain Dojo dialog which refers *MyModule.html*.

*MyModule.html* contain ContentPane which refers *MyView.html*.

*MyView.html* use binding with dojo/mvc/at

With this structure the binding work on Firefox, Chrome but not on Internet Explorer 8.

My second solution file system :

```
- Home.html
```

*Home.html* contain the code which use in *MyView.html* of the first solution. It use binding with dojo/mvc/at.

With this structure the binding work on all browser.

why is the first case not working ?

You can get the example here :
http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/378226/DojoBinding-zip.html